# how to keep two google drive document sync in part?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-apps, google-drive-realtime-api

Backgroud:
I need to keep updated doc2 editing doc1 that containing my intro.

- doc1.doc  Containing my intro
- doc2.doc  Containing rest of my content

example:

- doc1.doc

> Intro
>   This is my intro

- doc2.doc

> **Intro**
>   This is my intro     ////getting from doc1.doc
>  
>   
>   **Main Content** 
>   This is my intro

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can only achieve this using Google Apps Script (think Visual Basic Macros for Google Docs).

You could have:

doc1.doc containing your intro

doc2.doc containing your content

Then create a Google Apps Script that takes the text from each of those and updates a doc3.doc which will contain both the intro and content.  Here's a link to get you started on using Google Apps Script for Google Docs (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/docs)

EDIT - added some example code. (I just went through the tutorial and created this, I'd still advise you go through the tutorials on that link, they're quite useful).  Hope this helps you though.

Example code:

```
function createMergeDocument() {

  // Links to your documents
  var mergedUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ZZw990dzElGWxEmE7A6Vq9Zs7CKVWd-olzTBQpTJko4/edit?usp=sharing';
  var introUrl = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WDvWEiS-JmA1ZbDvgq7z5Gt6sLGFfD8oyDm6zoYCwQw/edit?usp=sharing';
  var contentUrl = "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1k0eetLMr4yBxJCTmeq4AAQYwX5EYQopyMXOtMWS2LEY/edit?usp=sharing";

  // Open your merged doc
  var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(mergedUrl);

  // Clear doc
  doc.getBody().setText("");

  // Get paragraphs from other documents
  var introText = getDoc(introUrl);
  var contentText = getDoc(contentUrl);

  // Add intro paragaphs
  for(var i=0; i < introText.length; i++) {
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph(introText[i].copy());
  }

  // New line
  doc.getBody().appendParagraph("");

  // Add content paragraphs
  for(var i=0; i < introText.length; i++) {
    doc.getBody().appendParagraph(contentText[i].copy());
  }
}

function getDoc(url) {
  var introDoc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(url);

  return introDoc.getBody().getParagraphs();

}
```

Comment: I alredy know that, but I was looking for a script doing this.

Comment: Updated with example code.  Note that you'll need to run the first function whenever you need to create the master document, they won't synchronise automatically.  You can however create a trigger so that whenever the intro or content documents are changed, the script is run.